# make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/hellocpp/main.o] Error 1

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am trying to port cocos2dx game on android plat from. When I build the project the following message appears

```
Build of configuration Release for project test_pro 

python /Users/itronix/Documents/Rizwan_Projects/cocos2dx_3_2/workspace/test_pro/proj.android/build_native.py -b release all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/Android.mk:cocos2dxandroid_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= main.cpp
make: /Users/itronix/Documents/Rizwan_Projects/cocos2dx_3_2/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/llvm-3.4/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/clang++: No such file or directory
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/hellocpp/main.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
The Selected NDK toolchain version was 4.8 !
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/itronix/Documents/Rizwan_Projects/cocos2dx_3_2/workspace/test_pro/proj.android/build_native.py", line 159, in <module>
    build(opts.ndk_build_param,opts.android_platform,opts.build_mode)
  File "/Users/itronix/Documents/Rizwan_Projects/cocos2dx_3_2/workspace/test_pro/proj.android/build_native.py", line 146, in build
    do_build(cocos_root, ndk_root, app_android_root,ndk_build_param,sdk_root,android_platform,build_mode)
  File "/Users/itronix/Documents/Rizwan_Projects/cocos2dx_3_2/workspace/test_pro/proj.android/build_native.py", line 82, in do_build
    raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ /Users/itronix/Documents/Rizwan_Projects/cocos2dx_3_2/workspace/test_pro/proj.android ] fails!
```

I am using using cocos2dx 3.2, NDK r9D, eclipse juno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally issue resolved... It may help you if you are facing same issue. First of all download ndk from this link

http://androids.zone/android-ndk/#.VQKVB4GUeh2

Then compile project from command line instead of eclipse.

**To comiple**

In terminal goto proj.android folder for your created project
and run this command

```
cocos run -p android -j 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says :
/Users/itronix/Documents/Rizwan_Projects/cocos2dx_3_2/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/llvm-3.4/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/clang++: No such file or directory

Make sure that clang++ file exists and your ndk is properly setup and is not missing any files.

Comment: Files exists and I checked it